# How do we fix these expressions so they don't exceed the margins?

Tags: align, typography

Consider:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
K_1&=\max \left \lbrace c_1(k)\int_M [D_1(k,y)-log(1+D_1(k,y))]\nu(dy),  c_2(k)\int_M [D_2(k,y)-log(1+D_2(k,y))]\nu(dy)\right \rbrace.
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
d V&= LV dt+((S-S_k^*+I-I_k^*)[\sigma_1(k)SdB_1 + \sigma_2(k) I dB_2]+a(k)\left(1- \frac{I_k^*}{I} \right)\sigma_2(k)dB_2\\
&+\int_M \left \lbrace \frac{1}{2}[D_1(k,y)S+D_2(k,y)I]^2+(S-S_k^*+I-I_k^*)[D_1(k,y)S+D_2(k,y)I]+a(k)[D_2(k,y)I-I_k^*\log(1+D_2(k,y))]\right \rbrace\tilde{N}(dt,dy)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've already found the idea of using more than one line in the second expression.  Why not do that for the first, and use even more lines for the second?

Comment: @Teepeemm Because for braces its not working, or maybe I haven't figured what to do..

Comment: You've already been told that `\left...\right` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: you asked about `\left` just now and were shown how to use `\bigl` instead

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand :) I'm trying to fix my thesis so I'm all over the place to be honest..

Comment: people don't mind helping but it is annoying if help is ignored and same question re-asked within minutes

Comment: @DavidCarlisle understand. I asked a sometime ago about whether someone can edit my LaTex file for my thesis to fix the typographic mistakes. I have noticed you are very good so if you could, I will pay for your time. Please let me know :)

Comment: no time, sorry:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I might do if I was editing this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
K_1={} & \begin{aligned}[t]
  \max\Bigl \lbrace & c_1(k)\int_M
    \bigl[D_1(k,y)-\log(1+D_1(k,y))\bigr]\nu(dy),
    \\
    & c_2(k)\int_M
    [D_2(k,y)-\log(1+D_2(k,y))]\nu(dy)\Bigr\rbrace.
\end{aligned}
\\
d V={} & LV dt+((S-S_k^*+I-I_k^*)[\sigma_1(k)SdB_1 + \sigma_2(k) I dB_2]
\\
&+a(k)\left(1- \frac{I_k^*}{I} \right)\sigma_2(k)dB_2\\
&+\int_M
\begin{aligned}[t]
  \smash[b]{\Bigl \lbrace}
  &
  \tfrac{1}{2}[D_1(k,y)S+D_2(k,y)I]^2
  \\
  &+(S-S_k^*+I-I_k^*)[D_1(k,y)S+D_2(k,y)I]
  \\
  & +a(k)[D_2(k,y)I-I_k^*\log(1+D_2(k,y))]\Bigr\rbrace\tilde{N}(dt,dy)
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Note that the trick of using `aligned` here only works well because there are no equation numbers.

As others already mentioned, use one `align*`, use manually scaled fences when they span a row break. Use `aligned` to have subalignment.

[image]

Comment: These are separate statements for different parts of the document

Comment: I have added one more adjustment, could you try it fix it please?

Comment: and it is hard to see how to separate them?

Comment: Not going to fix the edit. This site is not a `please do this for me` service. I'd recommend this PDF from the AMS. In it are the math breaking guidlines that I normally use https://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/mit-2.pdf

Comment: I believe if you move the `=` to the other side of the `&`, then you don't need the `{}`.

Comment: @Teepeemm yes, but here is it needed when both "rows" are in one `align*` and we are breaking the latter at `+`.